# Как проставлять аттрибут rel="nofollow" для всех ссылок в описании?(Yii2)

Tags: php, yii2

И можно ли добиться такого эффекта штатными методами фреймворка Yii2? В HTMLPurifer, UrlHelper, увы, не нашел нужной опции.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:
Так выглядит getter для вывод указанного момента сейчас. Всвойстве `$description` хранится HTML-контент, который очищает от потенциального вредоносного кода HTMLPurifier:

```
public function getDescription()
{
    return HtmlPurifier::process($this->description);
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в свой вопрос фрагмент кода, в котором у вас формируется этот текст со ссылками.

Comment: Фрагмент кода добавил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этого можно добиться через штатный конфиг HtmlPurifier так:

```php
public function getDescription()
{
    return HtmlPurifier::process($this->description, function (\HTMLPurifier_Config $config) {
        $config->set('HTML.Nofollow', true);
    });
}
```

или так:

```php
public function getDescription()
{
    $config = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $config->set('HTML.Nofollow', true);

    return HtmlPurifier::process($this->description, $config);
}
```

Как вам больше нравится оформление кода.

[Тут](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.Nofollow) можно найти описание этого и других параметров конфигурации HtmlPurifier.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вы можете воспользоваться функцией [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php):

```php
$description = str_replace('a href=', 'a rel="nofollow" href=', $this->description);
return HtmlPurifier::process($description);
```

либо воспользоваться функцией [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace) для замены по регулярному выражению:

```php
$description = preg_replace('/a\s+href="([\w\-.\/:]+)"/iu', 'a href="$1" rel="nofollow"', $this->description);
return HtmlPurifier::process($description);
```

но первый вариант будет работать быстрее.